# Android application for Stack Exchange global inbox notifications

Tags: support, notifications, android

Is it possible to have SE inbox notifications displayed on Android devices (tablets/phones)?

Comment: What do you mean? Notifications are displayed in the mobile view.

Comment: @slhck Sorry I have update OP that I need notification.

Comment: @slhck I think he wants a notification in the top bar instead of on the mobile site.

Comment: You could look around on StackApps.com.  I think this will work for what you want: [Stack Remote - Free Android app dedicated towards Stack Exchange sites!](http://stackapps.com/questions/3178/stack-remote-free-android-app-dedicated-towards-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yeah you got me. Please move your anser to an anser to get accepted and we can discuss more from there

Comment: @jadarnel27 I've tested `Stack Remote` as your suggestion but I find no notification there though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself - using email SO's native email notification feature as below snapshots, we can have notification for mobile devices via email notification.

[image]

[image]